# 1and1 mod_rewrite issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently trying to have my 1and1 host an .htaccess file with mod_rewrite enabled, it works on my local wamp, but it doesn't on the server,

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried removing everything but the mod_rewrite block and the issue still persists...

I've asked 1&1 for support, they closed my ticket without answering... o_O,

Please help!

.htaccess file:

```
#
# Dream Forgery Settings:
#
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite current-style URLs of the form 'strap.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /strap.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Edit:

I don't have access to apache logs as this is a shared hosting, but the functionality expected is to redirect urls for example:

http://example.com/arg1/arg2/arg3

to

http://example.com/strap.php?q=arg1/arg2/arg3

(it is currently giving 404 errors, only the 404 page from 1&1 shows up)

Comment: And what is the issue? Please explain what is working and what not.

Comment: I don't have access to apache logs as this is a shared hosting, but the functionality expected is to redirect urls for example:

http://example.com/arg1/arg2/arg3

to

http://example.com/strap.php?q=arg1/arg2/arg3

(it is currently giving 404 errors, and the custom 404 page doesn't show up, only the 404 page from 1&1 shows up)

Comment: Seems like the host doesn't support htaccess.

Comment: It appears to support htaccess because if I put some odd characters in it I get a 500 error... strange host...

Comment: So where does your `strap.php` reside on that new host?

Comment: At the root of the htdocs, this issue is now resolved, I found that "Options -MultiViews" at the top of my .htaccess fixed the issue. Thanks for looking at this anyway!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer here:

Adding the following fixed the mod-rewrite:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

http://www.techpopuli.net/news/04/002289.html

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked like a charm on my 1and1 server as well. Very annoying by the way...I was getting crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything but the important bits...

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite current-style URLs of the form 'strap.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /strap.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

...and see what happens. The rest of the file isn't necessary—this'll [hopefully] isolate the problem. And [1 & 1 supports .htaccess](http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/htaccess/1.html).

Comment: Just tried this exercise, it however didn't resolve the issue, I'm still seeing a 404 error from 1&1... :(, and strap.php is at the document root, .htaccess is at the document root as well... this is getting very annoying...!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue on a mutualised web hosting from 1and1.

Symptoms:

- frontend homepage ok
- frontend other page -> err500
- admin page ok
- being a 1and1 shared web hosting, no apache error_log available

Joomla 3.9 comes with a .htaccess (in the root directory) that messed it up at line 69:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Commenting this line does the trick.