# .htaccess Rewrite and subdirectories not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this as my .htaccess file:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^maps/(\w+)/?$ /maps.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

The second RewriteRule is working PERFECTLY! No problems. But, the first one, is giving me a huge headache... It just doesn't work at all. It's redirecting to /maps.php, but it doesn't gives me the parameter, which is BASIC for me. It's like the GET params are not there, but are supposed to be there. I don't get it...because I've just copied a working RewriteRule, from StackOverflow, and addapted changing the word "search" to the word "maps".

Could anybody, please, help me with this thing? I'm pretty sure it'd be something simple, but I'm not seeing it...

EDIT: Apparently, there is a second .htaccess file in my server. "/logs/.htaccess".

```
Options +Indexes
RemoveHandler .html
RemoveType .html
AddType text/html .html
Satisfy any
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from MY_SERVER_IP
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to /logs"
```

There is no way I can delete this file. Or I didn't manage to do it. My hosting provider is 1&1.

Comment: What is the URL you're trying? I don't see why the lang parameter wouldn't be set. BTW despite it doesn't seem to be the root of the issue you should add the `[L]` flag to the end of the rewrite rules to stop processing remaining rules (could introduce bugs).

Comment: What I'd like to have is that when I write www.mysite.com/maps/es it will be redirected to www.mysite.com/maps.php?lang=es If I try www.mysite.com/es, it works PERFECT. No problems. It seems to be a problem with the RewriteRule and subdirectories.

Comment: OK so when you visit www.mysite.com/maps/es you're rewritten to **maps.php** but the lang parameter is *not* es?

Comment: Exactly! But, if I take the RewriteRules out, it happens the same. So I'm thinking that the RewriteRule is doing nothing. The redirect happens because other reason...which I don't understand. :S

Comment: I see. Is that the entire contents of the .htaccess file?

Comment: I've update the main post. Now you can see the content's file.

Comment: It seems to be another .htaccess file, in "logs" directory with the content I've added to the question body.

Comment: The .htaccess file in your logs directory will only be applied to the logs directory and below, it shouldn't be relevant to your issue.

Comment: Solved!!! I've posted the solution. It was very annoying...some 1and1 thing...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem through some deep searching after I realized it could be a problem with my hosting provider, 1and1. And I got it here [1and1 mod_rewrite issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681959/1and1-mod-rewrite-issues)

It was about an option you MUST add in your .htacces file which is:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Now is working more than fine! Thanks to @kjetilh for the support.